# How to get only first part of string before slash in URL (HTACCESS)

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

To achieve this URL pattern **www.example.com/abc-xyz/mno-pqr/123.html**

I am using following in htaccess:

```
rewriterule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ index.php?lyrics_id=$3&singer=$1&song=$2 [L]
```

Below are example URL which are causing duplicate title error for my site.

```
www.example.com/abc-xyz/WHATEVER/ANOTHER_WHATEVER/mno-pqr/283.html
www.example.com/abc-xyz/I_DONT_WANT_THIS_PART/mno-pqr/283.html
www.example.com/abc-xyz/HELP_ME/REMOVE/mno-pqr/283.html
www.example.com/abc-xyz/HELP/REMOVE/THIS/PART/mno-pqr/283.html
```

I want to get only first part before slash in singer part. 
I want exactly this,

```
www.example.com/abc-xyz/mno-pqr/123.html
```

but not other letters or between abc-xyz and mno-pqr.

Help me writing htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you only want to match the url if it consists of exactly 3 parts. You can do this, by matching everything but the delimiter in each part. The delimiter here is `/`.

Also please note that `.` matches EVERY CHARACTER. If you want to match the period character instead, you have to escape it (`\.`).

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?lyrics_id=$3&singer=$1&song=$2 [L]
```

---

> That works for my 3 parameters rule but how to add 301 redirect to all
>   those URL which have more than 3 parts?

If the extra parts are always between the first part and the 2nd part of the url, like you showed above, you have to redirect the user with a 301 header:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/.*/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /$1/$2/$3.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, That works for my 3 parameters rule but how to add 301 redirect to all those URL which have more than 3 parts? I mean, now those page are showing 404 not found error, and I want to redirect them to www.example.com/abc-xyz/mno-pqr/123.html

Comment: Thank you very much. First, I tried by keeping this single line your provided which didnot work. but later I kept two lines, RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$  index.php?lyrics_id=$3&artist=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/.*/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /$1/$2/$3.html [R=301,L] and then it works